# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId [7887978]

Tags: java, bson

I am really facing challenge in changing String object to ObjectId using BSON API. The error I am facing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId [7887978]
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:130)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:124)
    at com.sample.common.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

The simple code below for reference:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "7887978";
        ObjectId id = new ObjectId(number);
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}
```

How we can solve this error. Any pointers ?

Edit: Maven dependency that I used:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the [Bson API doc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) it is clear that `ObjectId(String
>   hexString)` Constructs a new instance from a valid `24-byte
>   hexadecimal string` representation.

Point here is the `string` has to be a valid `24-byte` `hexadecimal` value.
The value `7887978` is invalid. You could either modify the code as below:

```
String id = "666f6f2d6261722d71757578";
        if (ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
            ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(id);
            System.out.println(objectId);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid id");
        }
```

or use the in build static API `get()` to create a new object id..

```
ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.get();
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

docs say :

> IllegalArgumentException - if the string is not a valid id

so perhaps  `"7887978"` is not a valid id

Comment: I am looking to simply convert String to ObjectId in java. I am not sure string is not valid. It should convert from one data type to another. What you say? Thanks, Sayali

Comment: @user4567570 your String should be a hexstring